# Using JSoup to parse Twitter

Tags: android, html, twitter, jsoup, user-agent

So here is my code:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlString)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36")
            .get();

    System.out.println(doc);
```

So I'm using JSoup, and trying to parse the HTML of a Twitter hashtag page (for reference, something like http://www.twitter.com/hashtag/stackexchange) on an Android app. For some reason though, I can't access the real HTML. I get either a mobile version, or an incomplete version. My userAgent is right I'm sure.

Any thoughts? I've looked everywhere, but typing "Twitter" and "JSoup" or "HTML" usually brings up Twitter feeds about JSoup and HTML.

Comment: are you loading mobile version https://mobile.twitter.com/

Comment: give us the urlString

Comment: The urlString changes depending on what I put it, but an example one would be "htttp://www.twitter.com/hashtag/stackexchange"

Comment: I didn't have any problems getting the first page. See e.g. http://try.jsoup.org/~0yfbSt4sJMW5OdgqxwRWOLgthO0 for URL, UA, and selector. Are you still having problems?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me, but some of the content is loaded with JS so you will need to use another library as Selenium or HTMLUnit to run javascript

JSoup is an HTML Parser using CSS Selectors